# Print from specific positions in NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numpy

I am new to NumPy and I have created the following array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

and I am wondering if there is a way to print a number from a specific position in the array.

Let's say I wanted to print number 7, and ONLY number 7. Would that be possible?

Comment: Do you plan to learn NumPy by asking a lot of questions here, or are you planning to read any of the documentation and other materials that abound on the net ?  If the former, be prepared for a lot of snide comments like this one, if the latter, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have read a tutorial and searched for a way to print a value from a specific position without result. For example: http://www.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial. But seeing your respons i guess i just haven't searched hard enough ;) thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seriously??!?

Print third row (index = 2), first column (index = 0)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> print a[2][0]
7
```

Comment: Thank you, yes sorry it was stupid of me to post such a question, i should've been able to find out myself.

Answer (score 4):

From [tentative NumPy tutorial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c)

```
>>> b
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [10, 11, 12, 13],
       [20, 21, 22, 23],
       [30, 31, 32, 33],
       [40, 41, 42, 43]])
>>> b[2,3]
23
```

The syntax is [row,column] each indexed from zero, so b[2,3] means third row, fourth column of b.